# How to debug JDK source code and add comments in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I compiled my own JDK, which is located in /home /fashion/desktop/openjdk , and
my vscode user settings.json  the content is

```json
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    //set project jdk
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
          "name": "JavaSE-15",
          "path": "/home/fashion/Desktop/openjdk/build/linux-x86_64-server-slowdebug/images/jdk",
          "sources": "/home/fashion/Desktop/openjdk/build/linux-x86_64-server-slowdebug/support/src.zip",
          // "sources": "/home/fashion/Desktop/src!/",
          "default": true,
        },
        {
            "name" :"JavaSE-14",
            "path" :"/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64",
        },
      ],
      //set editor jre
      "java.home" :"/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-amd64",
      "java.trace.server": "verbose"
}
```

According to this configuration, I can only step to JDK source code。（Java Source Code Not C/Cpp ,For example I Want to Step into System.out.prinf("HelloWorld"); )
But I can't add any comments, that is, I can't edit the source code of JDK.

How can I solve this problem？ thanks

Answer (score 1):

To debug JDK source code, you should install the extension C/C++. Also you need to configure C++ environment, please refer to [Using C++ on Linux in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux)

Open the JDK folder in VS Code, press Ctrl+F5 to go into debug, choose the environment **C++(GDB/LLDB)**, then in launch.json, set

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "compile java file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/.../jdk/bin/javac",
            "args": ["Main.java"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        },
        {
            "name": "run java project",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/..../jdk/bin/java",
            "args": ["Main"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Have a try.